# Gaussian integral from 0 to infinity

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

How can I do the following integral?

$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^{2}+\alpha^{2})}dx$

Thanks!

Comment: Use Gaussian integral: $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2}\, dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that $e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+\alpha^2)}=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}e^{-\frac{\alpha^2}{2}}$

Thus your integral become:

$e^{\frac{-\alpha^2}{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$

If you consider $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$ as an usual integral, then the result is easy to find.

Comment: It's better not to answer question with no effort...